# MySQL Workbench not present in MySQL Community RPM for Fedora 21

Tags: linux, fedora, mysql

I have given up trying to find a proper workaround or solution to install MySQL Workbench + MariaDB so I decided to install the *official* stack provided by MySQL so I enabled their YUM repository using their [RPM for Fedora 21](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/) available at their download page but when I tried to install Workbench yum throws the following message:

> There isn't any package named **mysql-community-workbench.**

How long do I have to wait until they enable workbench on their repositories? Although I can use the el7 build, the result rows are all blank so it's not useful at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried with mysql-workbench-community-6.2.4-1.fc20.x86_64.rpm but still result rows are all blank. Maybe one of the dependencies of mysql workbench is not compatible with it in Fedora 21 (in other forums glib is mentioned, see:   stackoverflow.com/questions/24739198/mysql-workbench-not-displaying-query-results ).

But those answers are made only for Ubuntu, not Fedora.

Another option that I've found here: bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72585

To do that, do the next steps:

1. Download source code from dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/
2. Be sure to have latest glib libraries and dependencies (use yum to get it)
3. Be sure to have boost C library (use yum to get it)
4. Unpack mysql-workbench source code tar.
5. Change to source code directory and make a new directory called wb-build; change dir to wb-build.
6. Backup mysql-workbench-community-6.2.4-src/backend/wbpublic/sqlide/recordset_text_storage.cpp
7. Edit file:
   mysql-workbench-community-6.2.4-src/backend/wbpublic/sqlide/recordset_text_storage.cpp

Use vi or gedit and change the method call ‘ReloadIfChanged()’ to ‘ReloadAllIfChanged()’ in the lines 206, 215 and 224. Then save your changes.

8. Make it compile as root inside wb-build directory:

   - `cmake .. -DBUILD_CONFIG=mysql_release`
   - `make`
   - `make install`

This method `ReloadIfChanged()` is deprecated: see code.google.com/p/ctemplate/ Ctemplate's method stops the make process if not changed.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://superuser.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers. See the [tour] for why Me Too answers are not appropriate here.

Comment: I'm sorry Tim, I'll take care about with you mentioned. I've changed my "answer" to a real answer. Regards

Comment: So basically I'm rebuilding mysql from its repos right? well, I'll give it a shot, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

mysql-workbench is not yet available for Fedora 21 and I'm not sure whether this package is ever included in their YUM repository.

The best approach is to download mysql-workbench rpm for Fedora 20 (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/6.2.html)  and install it using **yum localinstall < rpmfile >**

Comment: Thank you, and what about its dependencies?

Comment: yum would take care of the dependencies.

Comment: Attempting to install the Fedora 20 package does not work. The difference in ctemplate cause the result set in the UI to be blank, see here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173797/how-to-install-mysql-workbench-on-fedora-21